# Is this bad code?

Tags: c++, performance, polymorphism

I've been using this code style for a while now, I normally make a class that has "ID" in front of it, place it in a header, then make a .cpp file and put a class called "IDClassnameLocal". I make pure virtual functions in the abstract header class, then make normal virtual functions in the .cpp class and have it inherit the abstract header class.

Is this bad code design and am I coding efficiently?

- I put ID(identification) in front of the class name to prevent redefinition and for cleanness.

Example:

```
// Player.h // ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class IDPlayer {
public:
    virtual ~IDPlayer(void) {} // Destructor

    virtual void PlayerData(void) = 0;
    virtual void Controls(void) = 0;
};
extern IDPlayer* idplayer;

// Player.cpp // //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class IDPlayerLocal : public IDPlayer {
public:
    IDPlayer(void) {} // Constructor

    virtual void PlayerData(void);
    virtual void Controls(void);
};
IDPlayerLocal idplayerLocal;
IDPlayer* idplayer = &idplayerLocal;
// Class Function Definitions
void IDPlayerLocal::PlayerData(void) {
    Player.X = 400;
    Player.Y = 500;

    Player.W = 20;
    Player.H = 20;

    Player.VelocityX = (float)0.31;
    Player.VelocityY = (float)0.31;
}

void IDPlayerLocal::Controls(void) {
    if(::MainGame) {
        if(KEY_DOWN(0x41)) { // A
            Player.X = Player.X - Player.VelocityX;
            if(Player.X <= 0)
                Player.X = 0;
        }
        if(KEY_DOWN(0x44)) { // D
            Player.X = Player.X + Player.VelocityX;
            if(Player.X+Player.W >= 650)
                Player.X = 650 - Player.W;
        }
        if(KEY_DOWN(0x57)) { // W
            Player.Y = Player.Y - Player.VelocityY;
            if(Player.Y <= 0)
                Player.Y = 0;
        }
        if(KEY_DOWN(0x53)) { // S
            Player.Y = Player.Y + Player.VelocityY;
            if(Player.Y+Player.H >= 570)
                Player.Y = 570 - Player.H;
        }
        if(KEY_DOWN(VK_SPACE)) {

        }
    }
}


// Core.cpp // ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// ...
// Intialized Data //
idplayer->PlayerData();

while(TRUE) {
    // ...
    // Loop Data //
    idplayer->Controls();
    // ...
}
// ...
```

Comment: What does "ID" stand for?

Comment: I'm guessing "Interface Definition". (Or description.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz It means "identification". Just a typical abbreviation and keeps things organized. I added a note in the question explaining why.

Comment: @selbie Explained above, and in the question(edited).

Comment: @TristanGibson use namespaces. This is C++, not Objective-C.

Comment: @Zoidberg I'll keep that in mind, thanks. Also, I've never used Objective-C.

Comment: @TristanGibson The only "real" answer to that question is [get a book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel Wouldn't that apply to almost every question?

Comment: I'm just confused as to why you would do all this? Don't misunderstand - sometimes this sort of thing makes sense, but it doesn't make sense *all the time*.

Comment: @NikBougalis What do you mean?

Comment: @TristanGibson It sounds every class you create is designed as an interface. Why? Sometimes that makes sense, but not all the time. If this your "standard" design something is, almost certainly, wrong.

Comment: @NikBougalis I'm not sure when and when not to make a class an interface. Maybe when I use the abstract class for multiple classes to derive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as you are using the same style throughout your code no style is really bad unless unreadable. I was able to go through your code without so much trouble so I would say it is a good style. Just be consistent throughout your project.

Comment: Do you know if it's efficient?

Comment: @TristanGibson Define "efficient".

Comment: @TristanGibson : Making everything virtual for no apparent reason is certainly _not_ efficient.

Comment: @ildjarn Well, they are virtual because the .cpp class is deriving them.

Comment: @TristanGibson Something tells me you aren't very clear on C++ and don't quite understand the point of class derivation or virtual functions. You can have derived classes without needing virtual functions.

Comment: @TristanGibson : And why is there a derived class to begin with? Why not just a single class, declared in a header, and defined either in the same header or in some .cpp?

Comment: @Danny And I would disagree - being consistent is a good thing no doubt, but you can be consistently bad which... well, just isn't good.

Comment: @ildjarn I don't know when I should use derived classes and I also don't really understand why I put virtual functions in them. I just read that was what I was supposed to do.

Comment: @TristanGibson : You read that about C++, or some other language? For non-COM-oriented _C++_ this is a rare approach, unlike, say, Java. :-]

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing may be useful in certain cases, but certainly not for all classes. You need to consciously decide whether this is appropriate for your class. So adopting this approach as a 'code style' would be a bad thing.

Answer (score 0):

- You don't need to comment constructors or destructors. Nor the name of the file but here it is ok we can't see what blocks goes to what file without them
- extern IDPlayer* idplayer is a global. It smells bad but might be ok
- `IDPlayer* idplayer = &idplayerLocal` Is there a reason you don't use a reference (`IDPlayer& idplayer = idplayerLocal`)
- X, Y, W, H seems weird to be in caps. Usually caps have special meanings. I don't think you should do that
- `(float)0.31` is weird. Either plainly do `0.31` or use a suffix like f (float) or d (double) (I think I can't remember my suffix).
- `::MainGame` another global but in games i do have a global so its fine. But do you really need to use `::`? Its not bad but seems funny i wouldnt think to search `if(::`
- Not a problem but are you sure you want W and S, A and D to cancel eachother out?
- Is KEY_DOWN a macro? why isnt it a function? Also instead of hex code of the ascii letter just use KEY_DOWN('A')
- Usually I have `while(gameRunning)` and not `true`. Unless you have complicated ifs to break out of the loop then its good to use while(true) or while(1)

Comment: It's using DirectX and Win32 API. I normally use :: global scoping because it's easier for me to recognize globals. KEY_DOWN is a constant: 
#define KEY_DOWN(vk_code) ((GetAsyncKeyState(vk_code) & 0x8000) ? 1 : 0)   
#define KEY_UP(vk_code) ((GetAsyncKeyState(vk_code) & 0x8000) ? 0 : 1)

Comment: oh right i forgot my windoze api. It was actually not that difficult much of the time.

Comment: "Is there a reason you don't use a reference" Should I use a reference instead?

Comment: @TristanGibson: Yes, if it never will be null, should always exist and won't change use a reference. The only time I don't use a reference is when a 3rd party library force me not to.